# Pyspark: how to run a query to compute the average of a given value?

Tags: sql, pyspark

I created a table `myTable` from a .csv file as you in the following

```
schema= StructType([
        StructField("identifier", StringType(), True),
        StructField("identifier_type", StringType(), True),
        StructField("timestamp", TimestampType(), True),
        StructField("device_lat", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("device_lon", FloatType(), True)])

myTable = spark.read.format("csv").schema(schema).option("timestampFormat","yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss").load('myFile.csv')
myTable = myTable[myTable['device_lat']>0]
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(myTable, "myTable")

+--------------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+----------+
|          identifier|identifier_type|          timestamp|       lat|       lon|
+--------------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+----------+
|68d62a1b-b928-422...|           gggx|2020-01-19 03:03:00|  44.80817| -73.52296|
|1675a629-a010-44b...|           gggx|2020-01-18 21:15:42| 42.103893|-76.799164|
|0fe7a0b7-028e-459...|           gggx|2020-01-18 23:39:54|  43.18203| -77.67202|
|4caa7437-6a59-4aa...|           gggx|2020-01-18 18:27:14| 43.092876| -79.05402|
+--------------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+----------+
```

I would like to run a query that computes the hourly average for each day and for each user.

I would like to have something like the following where the values are not real and the column `hour` it is just to show that each user should `24` rows per day

```
myTable

identifier      identifier_type      day       hour      mean_lat   mean_lon
    A               gggx          2020-01-18     0       44.80817   -73.52296
    A               gggx          2020-01-18     1       44.80817   -73.52296
    .                 .               .          .          .          .
    .                 .               .          .          .          .
    .                 .               .          .          .          .
    A               gggx          2020-01-18     22       44.80817   -73.52296
    A               gggx          2020-01-18     23       44.80817   -73.52296
    A               gggx          2020-01-19     0        44.80817   -73.52296
    A               gggx          2020-01-19     1        44.80817   -73.52296
```

Comment: Do you want spark or SQL solution?

Comment: @GMB I use to run `spark.sql` queries to extract the data.

Comment: What if a user has not data for more a given hour?

Comment: we can just drop that row but I would need a column that indicates the day and the hour for each data